# How to create a responsive dialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dialog

I'm trying to style a Dialog() widget; but it doesn't realy let me deal with height and widht as I'd usually do it.

In a nutshell: I placed all content in a Container and I want that container to only be as high as it needs to be. But the Dialog() widget seems to only let me set it's size by manipulating the insetPadding. Code first, screenshot below.

**Code:**

```
    class _CustomDialogueState extends State<CustomDialogue> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        insetPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25.w, 108.h, 25.w, 185.h),
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        //
        child: Stack(
          //clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(//THIS IS THE CONTAINER HOLDING ALL THE CONTENT
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.r),
                  color: Provider.of<CustomColors>(context, listen: false)
                      .customColorScheme['White']),
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.w, 50.h, 10.w, 10.h),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  //
                  SizedBox(height: 45.h),
                  //
                  Text(
                    'Welcome to THREE THINGS',
                    style: Provider.of<CustomTextStyle>(context, listen: false)
                        .customTextStyle('Main 1'),
                  ),
                  //
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12.h,
                  ),// MORE CONTENT FROM HERE; BUT NOT RELEVANT FOR THE ISSUE; SEE SEESREENSHOT
```

**Screenshot of three emulated devices:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before. Just add a SingleChildScrollView in the child of Dialog.

Comment: Can you explain why this solution works? What is the cause of the problem and how this solution solve it?

Comment: I have to admit, I was sceptical of this, but it works like a charm. The secondI wrapped the scrollchild around the Dialog's child (in this case the Stack widget), the Container widget behaved normally again. BUT: I experimented a bit and just wrapping it in a Column works as well. My guess is that the Dialog forces max constraints on its child and you need something to break the connection; but we'd need someone a bit more pro in Fluter fundamentals to really explain what is going on here and which widgets can be used to acheive the goal. In my case: The column is fine.

Answer (score 1):

We have two types of responsive that you can read in [this article](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive),
If you want responsive widgets you need to pass dynamic values in height and width, not fixed!

1. first solution is `MediaQuery`, like this:

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4, 
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8, // pass this line to your container to change heigth due to device heigth
// you need to change values as you needed bigger or smaller
```

> Im not sure about values but You can get device width or heigth by these two lines and fix pixel overflow and play around to get best

2. We have another way to control boxconstraints too, you can use [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to do that but i think `MediaQuery` is better in this case.

maybe its good idea to give `padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.all(15)` to `Container` just for test! im not sure about result